# Showing the line count of a specific file

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, cat

Is this the correct way to show the line count of a specific file?

```
cat file | grep * -c
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use this command:

`wc -l <file>`

This will return the total line number count in the provided file.

Answer (score 1):

Your shell will "expand" the asterisk in `grep * -c` to everything in the current directory, resulting in, for instance:

```
grep foo bar baz -c
```

Which is not what you want.

Try `cat file | grep -c .` to count the number of rows containing at least a printable character, or `cat file | wc -l` to count the number of lines.

If the input is a file, however, you may consider giving access to the file instead of piping it on stdin, to the command that does the counting. (for example `wc -l file` or `grep . -c file`).

If you don't want `wc` to show the filename when giving it a filename, you can extract the first word of the output of `wc -l` with your favorite filter, such as `cut(1)`: `wc -l foo | cut -d' ' -f 1` or `awk(1)`: `wc -l foo | awk '{print $1}'`, or something else with the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Number all non-empty lines:

```
cat file | nl
```

Or include everything:

```
cat file | nl -ba
```